# Installing and initializing symfony on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: symfony, ubuntu

I tried almost all the solutions provided on the internet. Nothing seems to work.it says

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
-installation request for symfony/symfony v2.8.4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v.2.8.41].

-symfony/symfony v2.8.41 requires ext-xml *-> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.

Comment: Did you try to activate the `xml` extension?

Comment: And be aware the Symfony 2 is not going to run under php 7.  So make sure you install php 5.6.  The Digital Ocean site has some excellent documentation on installing ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mentioned the system on which you run Symfony and which PHP version you use.

- For Ubuntu with PHP 7 you just need to install the xml extension through apt: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml`
- For Windows you can follow the guidelines in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/fa/install.windows.extensions.php)
- For Mac OS X you can use a package installer like Homebrew or [use a tool](https://php-osx.liip.ch) which will install many package at once

After that, make sure the extensions are enabled in your PHP ini file.